# Can somebody please explain me this code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm not a core JavaScript developer. I'm stuck to understand below code :-

```
export const getSupervisor = createSelector(
  [getAllOrgChartUsers, getUserById],
  (users, child) => users.get(child.get('parent'))
);
```

Can someone pls explain me whole code functioning here...especially what is this comma (,) doing after this line `[getAllOrgChartUsers, getUserById],` ?

What I'm able to guess is each function i.e. getAllOrgChartUsers() and getUserById() is doing something and returning some data which we are passing into this ES6 anonymous looking like function by using this brackets `(users, child)` ? Is it so? If correct then instead of comma, don't we have semi-colon (;) to terminate the first line of statement i.e. `[getAllOrgChartUsers, getUserById],` and then move to another independent line?

Please explain to me, thanks

Comment: `createSelector` gets 2 arguments. First is an array of functions, second is a function.

Comment: Think of it like this... `let funcs = [getAllOrgChartUsers, getUserById]; let cb = function(users, child) { return users.get(child.get("parent")) }; const getSupervisor = createSelector(funcs, cb);`

Comment: FYI... `,` = _comma_, `:` = _colon_, `;` = _semi-colon_

Comment: thanks @phil, sorry for my confusion between comma and colon...I have edited it

Comment: Thank you @phil...for making me explain this concept :)

Comment: Thank you @adiga ...for making me explain this concept :)